# skip document.ready to be called while browser back button

Tags: jquery, asp.net, internet-explorer, webforms

Is there a way i can restrict document.ready function to be when page loaded from browser back button.

obviously the page is loaded from browser cache.

please suggest any work around for the same.

Note: I tried with Javascript.NavationMode = 'fast' to skip this. as doc says its applicable only to Opera. i need to fix this in IE+ .

Comment: I would use a cookie  to decided if it has already loaded. let me know if you need more info.

Comment: Try to Check this condition (document.referrer == windows.location.href)